# Remote desktop login denied on 2008R2

Tags: remote-desktop, login, windows-server-2008-r2

We have two RDC servers, one running Server 2003 and the other running Server 2008R2, both relying upon the separate domain controller for remote desktop user authentication.

On the 2003 server, the non-admin user running Windows 7 can login. On the 2008R2 server, the same user's login is denied remote desktop connection. The user is a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.

The Remote Desktop Connection message is "The connection was denied because the user is not authorized for remote login.

What is happening and what do I do to make the user login succeed at the 2008R2 server?